# Chicago- Paraphrasing a whole page from Author into 1 paragraph- what is the citation?

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style

In a technical paper I am writing, I am taking a whole page of information and condensing it into a paragraph. I am using a mix of the authors words and my own. My question is can I cite the end of the paragraph and just state in the footnote that all the above is from page 124 of this author and I do not take credit for the information.

I would have rewritten it totally but this author's writing of this information cannot be rewritten given the nature of the info. It also saves having a whole paragraph from having 8 footnotes. This is all in chicago style. Is the following okay?

Example: 
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
..
..
..footnote 1

Footnote 1: author, title, page, paragraph is a slightly briefer summary of the abstract construction of x given by y. The paragraph is in a large part paraphrasing y and should not be taken as my own developed account.

Is this kosher?

Answer (score 2):

This is done all the time. You just write your paragraph, put a superscripted number or whatever reference method you're using at the end, and give the usual information about the source you drew this information from in a footnote or endnote. A citation does not have to be, and very often is not, an exact quote. If you give an exact quote, put it in quotation marks. If you paraphrase, don't put it in quotation marks.